# Find out what 'apt-get install' did

Tags: software-installation, apt, package-management

How can I find out what commands a package ran to install the software with `apt-get install <package>`?

For example, if I install a package that creates a user, how can I find out how it created that user?

Comment: The [event flow of the package management](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_the_event_flow_of_the_package_management) and [more info](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts).

Comment: @illuminÉ Ah, the debian reference is still active? I recall submitting some patches for it once.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes I find even when it's old or even obsoleted their apt documentation is still very rich!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You look at the post-installation script, which is actually run by dpkg. You can find these in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. Such scripts contain the name of the binary package in question, and have the suffix `.postinst`.

Note that there are also pre-installation scripts, which have the suffix `.preinst`, but I think that a package is much more likely to create a new user in a `postinst` script.

Did you have a particular example in mind?

An example is postgresql-common, which creates the `postgres` user. Here is an extract from the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-common.postinst`.

```
   # Make sure the administrative user exists
    if ! getent passwd postgres > /dev/null; then
        adduser --system --quiet --home /var/lib/postgresql --no-create-home \
            --shell /bin/bash --group --gecos "PostgreSQL administrator" postgres
    fi
```

Comment: WOW.. read my mind. I was actually trying to figure out how the postgresql package creted the user.

Answer (score 2):

What `apt-get install` does is executing `dpkg -i` on the packages.

To find out what a package does while installing you have to unpack it. Look in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` if your package is still there.

Inside the package is a data archive (`data.tar.gz`) and a control archive (`control.tar.gz`). Inside the control archive is a script to execute after the installation (`postint`) and one to execute after deleting the package (`postrm`). Open those scripts in an editor and see what the installation process does.

To unpack the package:

```
ar x package.deb
```

To unpack the control archive (after unpacking the package):

```
tar xfz control.tar.gz
```

Comment: I marked Faheem's answer as the solution because it is more specific to what I needed, but both answers complement each other.

Comment: Or since OP is on Debian (or a Debian-derivative, or at least using dpkg), `dpkg-deb -c package.deb outdir` is easier than the `ar`/`tar` combo. And will continue to work, even when dpkg changes formats (not sure if control.tar will change to xz)